# Which way data is encrypted in *.networkConnect files in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, encryption, settings, vpn

I need to find an easy way (few clicks solution) for **Mac OS X** users to **import VPN IPSec connection**. I found out that **there is a way** in Mac OS X to **export network connection settings** in **"System Preferences" -> "Network"**.

During export of network connection **.networkConnect** file is creating which **contains sensitive data** such as **ExportedSharedSecret** and **ExportedPassword** encrypted by some algorythm and after this encoded with base46.

I wonder **what algorythms are used** in order **to encrypt this sensitive data** and how can i **create such .networkConnect files under linux**, so users can download generated .networkConnect files from my server and import VPN settings to theis Mac OS X?

Here is an example **.networkConnect** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>L2TP</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UserConfigs</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>EAP</key>
                <dict/>
                <key>IPSec</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>AuthenticationMethod</key>
                    <string>SharedSecret</string>
                    <key>ExportedSharedSecret</key>
                    <data>
                    EPANULrdr4/H5mwY6iBGprwzIYfWG4Ep
                    </data>
                </dict>
                <key>PPP</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>AuthName</key>
                    <string>my_account</string>
                    <key>AuthPasswordEncryption</key>
                    <string>Keychain</string>
                    <key>CommRemoteAddress</key>
                    <string>192.168.1.8</string>
                    <key>ExportedPassword</key>
                    <data>
                    EPANVaLSgprCymwK5iBH0l/KJ1C3wBkh
                    </data>
                    <key>UserDefinedName</key>
                    <string>my_configuration</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses XOR with hard-coded key. Below is a simple Python demo.

```
import base64

cryptotext = base64.b64decode("EPANULrdr4/H5mwY6iBGprwzIYfWG4Ep")

decryption_key = [0x7d, 0x89, 0x52, 0x23, 0xd2, 0xbc, 0xdd, 0xea, 0xa3, 0xb9, 0x1f]

i = 0
cleartext = ""

for ch in cryptotext:
    cleartext += chr(ord(ch) ^ decryption_key[i])
    i += 1
    i = i % len(decryption_key)

print("%s" %(cleartext))
```

Comment: I wonder, what is this data after zero-byte in cleartext variable after script is done?

Comment: I should have added exit on null byte occurrence in decrypted buffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've helped me very well.

Comment: I think the original question is about how to generate the networkConnect file. It's really about encryption, not decryption, thought the code about decryption helps to gain insights, too.